# How to update jQuery script after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

I'm using this jQuery snippet to set equal height columns for divs with CSS class .equal:

```
    $(window).bind('load', function() {
        var blocks = $('.equal');
            var maxHeight = 0;
            blocks.each(function(){
                maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, parseInt($(this).css('height')));
            });
            blocks.css('height', maxHeight);
    });
```

Everything is working ok except on one subpage where I load part of the another subpage with this jQuery snippet:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.module-ct').html('<div><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
        $('.module-ct').load('index.php&Itemid=974 .genericItemList',
            function() {
                $('.module-ct .genericItemView:gt(2)').remove();
            }
        );
    });
```

Because of the size of this "external content" (it's from the same site), it's loaded after first snippet takes effect so equal height column are too small.

How could I update first script after second script is finished?

I hope I was clear enough, you can also see this on the bottom of this page: http://mkl3.mklj.si/index.php/knjiznica-bezigrad2

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you run the first snippet a second time?

Comment: That's exactly what I would like to do, I tried couple of methods but I couldn't update height of the columns.

Comment: I was saying declare the first function (the one passed to bind) with a name so that you can call it inside the ready function too. However, I tried pasting the first code into the console, and it doesn't seem to fix your problem. It looks like `$` isn't `jQuery`, so that might be part of your problem.

Comment: Ok, I declared first function with a name. I named it `var equalHeigth`, you can see it [here](http://pastebin.com/GHLgw3PS). When I call it inside first function (bind) it works. But how can I call it from second function (ready)? If I simply put `equalHeigth();` inside  it I get "equalHeigth is not defined". I'm not too good with JS so I'm a little lost here. jQuery insted $ is there because of the conflicts.

Comment: I've managed to solve this, I simply put whole equalHeigth() function inside ready function and called it from there.

But now I have another problem.
I'm using Bootstrap 3 collapse and I'm calling equalHeigth() function again there on collapse event like this: 
`code jQuery('#bsaccordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    equalHeigth();
})` so heights are recalculated.
Now I need to revert this action on hiden.bs.collapse event (when I hide collapsible element). How could I do that?

Comment: I haven't used Bootstrap; can you do this: `jQuery('#bsaccordion').on('shown.bs.collapse, hidden.bs.collapse', equalHeigth)`?